# ForEach with Try/Catch Error Handling

Tags: powershell, try-catch

Here's my code so far:

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -Path U:\Powershell\Move-Files\Clients |
           ?{$_.PsIsContainer} |
           Select -ExpandProperty FullName

Get-ChildItem -Path U:\Powershell\Move-Files\Individual | ?{
    !($_.PsIsContainer)
} | %{
    #Part of the file to match
    $File = ($_.name.substring(0,$_.basename.length-11))
    $File = ($File -split '_')[1] + ", " + ($File -split '_')[0]
    # Find matching Directory
    $Path = $Folders | ?{$_ -match $File}

    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path -ErrorAction Silently Continue

    Write-Host "Moved $_.FullName to $Path"
}
```

Basically, I have a lot of files named `First_Last (MMM yyyy).pdf` and this takes each file and creates a **variable** in the format of `Last, First` so that it can do a partial match and move the files to the destination folders (which are formatted `Last, First ##-####`). This all works fine, except I'm having trouble implementing `try/catch` error handling.

I replaced the line that starts with `Move-Item` with:

```
try {
  Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  "Moved $_.FullName to $Path successfully" | Add-Content U:\Powershell\Move-Files\log.txt
} catch {
  "Error moving $_.FullName" | add-content U:\Powershell\Move-Files\log.txt
}
```

It works *almost perfectly*, except that the `catch` doesn't properly report which files are not being moved. The `try` part reads out fine in the log. But the `catch` will just read the following in the log:

> Error moving Cannot process argument because the value of argument "destination" is null. Change the value of argument "destination" to a non-null value..FullName

Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current object (`$_`) in the `catch` block is the error/exception, not the current object from the operation that raised the exception. If you want to output the path in the error message you need to put it in a variable:

```
try {
  $file = $_.FullName
  Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $Path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  "Moved $file to $Path successfully" | Add-Content 'U:\Powershell\Move-Files\log.txt'
} catch {
  "Error moving $file" | Add-Content 'U:\Powershell\Move-Files\log.txt'
}
```

---

As a side note: PowerShell does only simple variable expansion in strings. `"$_.FullName"` will be expanded to the string representation of `$_` followed by the string `".FullName"`. If you want to expand a property of the current object you need either a subexpression:

```
"Error moving $($_.FullName)"
```

string concatenation:

```
"Error moving " + $_.FullName
```

or the format operator:

```
"Error moving {0}" -f $_.FullName
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was something simple like that. Thank you very much it is working great now.